# I need the value of the parent node

Tags: qxmlquery

I need the value of a parent node attribute

```
<Cases>
    <Case tag="IT653294" requesting="IT" >
       <Races>
        <Race scheduled="2018-06-01" id="100"/>
       </Races>
    </Case>
   <Case tag="IT831787" requesting="AB">
      <Races>
       <Race scheduled="2018-06-02" id="101" />
      </Races>
   </Case>
<Cases>


 SELECT  
    FROM xml  xx
    ,XMLTABLE (XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.my.nl/hello') ,
    'for $i in Cases/Case/Races/Race return $i'
               PASSING xx.XMLDOC 
               COLUMNS scheduled  Date PATH '@scheduled'
                          id      NUMBER PATH '@id' ) x
```

this gives :

2018-06-01  100
2018-06-02  101

what I need is :

```
 SELECT  
   FROM xml  gxml
 ,XMLTABLE (XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.my.nl/hello') ,
    'for $i in Cases/Case/Races/Race return $i'
               PASSING gxml.XMLDOC 
               COLUMNS scheduled  Date PATH '@scheduled'
                          id      NUMBER PATH '@id'
                          tag     varchar2(20) PATH ?? ) x
```

2018-06-01  100 IT653294
2018-06-02  101 IT831787

so, i Need the tag value from the parent. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks you all for your help

Comment: Or any other way to find the scheduled tane belonging to the tag and requestor. Have tried everthing. Please help

Comment: Ok, I don't thinks my question is gonna be answered. But however I really would like to know why? Is the question understandable? unreadable? to simple? to complex? impossible? or am I at the wrong place for XMLquery questions?